# Simplifying/combining nested LESS

Tags: css, less

I have the following LESS:

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
  padding-top: 0;
  z-index: 2010;
  li:first-child {
    a.disabled.heading {
      &.availableAction {
        border-top: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is there a way to combine the `li:first-child`, `a.disabled.heading`, and `&.availableAction` selectors?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
  padding-top: 0;
  z-index: 2010;
  li:first-child a.disabled.heading.availableAction {
    border-top: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

LESS supports nesting but never requires that you use it.

---

Unasked for notes :)

- Hope that z-index is arbitrary-looking and huge for a reason
- if possible, design your selector names so that you can say `.dropdown-menu` rather than `ul.dropdown-menu` - the browser will process the first one more quickly than the second
- if possible, it's good practice to use a less specific selector than `ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child a.disabled.heading.availableAction`. Again, browsers will process something like `.dropdown li:first-child .availableAction` more quickly (and `li:first-child .availableAction` even quicker, but I can imagine that might target things you don't want to target), and it'll make it easier for you to override the styles with other classes further down the cascade.